# ssh use rsync and backup to local

Tags: php, linux, ssh, rsync

I have a website on a remote server and wish to get a backup copy locally in an automated process. This all owrked great until we moved some sites to a new provider (fasthosts) who have an extremely restrictive ssh interface where zip and tar are either disabled or not installed (nor can be) so we decided to go down the route of incremental backup. We got it working with no issues by copying the htdocs to a backup folder with this command (Note we access the server with ssh)

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress /home/something/foo/bar/user/htdocs/  /home/something/foo/bar/user/backup/
```

or simply `rsync -avs /home/something/foo/bar/user/htdocs/  /home/something/foo/bar/user/backup/`

but obviously we need to get the files local. The docs say to use the host, Is this possible? my host is localhost obviously.

The following do not work (which i kind of expected but what should it be. rsync is very vague about this configuration

```
rsync -avs /home/hp3-linc1-nfs1-x/293/35293/user/htdocs/  root@backup.eclipse-creative.com:/home/backup/sync

rsync -avs /home/hp3-linc1-nfs1-x/293/35293/user/htdocs/  root@localhost:/home/backup/sync

rsync -avs /home/hp3-linc1-nfs1-x/293/35293/user/htdocs/  root@127.168.0.1:/home/backup/sync

rsync -avs /home/hp3-linc1-nfs1-x/293/35293/user/htdocs/  user@backup.eclipse-creative.com:/home/backup/sync

rsync -avs /home/hp3-linc1-nfs1-x/293/35293/user/htdocs/  user@localhost:/home/backup/sync

rsync -avs /home/hp3-linc1-nfs1-x/293/35293/user/htdocs/  user@127.168.0.1:/home/backup/sync
```

Any pointers would be well received.

The intention is to reintegrate our internal backup system with fasthosts (who appear to have a policy to lockout all backup methods so the paid service is used)

Answer (score 1):

Run rsync locally, with the server's username & hostname/IP as the rsync source location

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress user@server:/home/something/foo/bar/user/htdocs/  /home/something/foo/bar/user/backup/
```

you might not need StrictHostKeyChecking & UserKnownHostsFile

Comment: Hi there, My server is the pc i used to ssh into the server, would this be localhost 127.0.0.1 or something else? is there a way to find the username and hostname from say php? i ssh into the remote server from a local dev machine, is there no simple way to send data down the tunnel without needing to know the host and user, afterall ssh is a secure handshake right? or am i missing the point completely here

Comment: The server's your remote server's IP address or hostname, basically the address that you're copying from, so whatever username & server you normally ssh into.

Comment: ah got it, had to install rsync local etc but got it to work with the code in the answer. biggest catch i had was that the user of the script wasnt me but the system.